# "fancy someone" and other expressions

Tags: difference, phrases, expressions

Explain me some expressions, about relationships, please:

- fancy someone;
- go out together;
- ask someone out;
- fix someone up.

It's all about first contact, but can I substitute one for the other, without changing the meaning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each of these phrases is distinct from the others, so you cannot substitute one for any of the others.

- to *fancy someone* is to be attracted to someone
- to *go out together* is to go on a date with someone or can also be used to mean to be in a relationship with someone
- to *ask someone out* is to ask someone on a date or can also be used to ask someone to start a relationship
- to *fix someone up* is to *matchmake*

You can use all four in one scenario:

> Jack told me he **fancied** Jane, and Jane was an old friend of mine, so I decided to **fix them up** with one another. Jack ended up **asking her out** last Friday, and they **went out together** on Saturday.

"Fancy" is not typically used in American English in this context (as a verb), but if I recall correctly, its use is not uncommon in British English.

Comment: Very much a British English phrase, so you'll run into it in the UK and her former colonies.

Comment: @DamienH: usually, when something is "very much" or "typically" a British English phrase, it means you will _not_ run into it very much in the former colonies (it usually means that such a phrase is, for instance, not standard American English). If it is used in Britain and (most) former colonies, it is usually considered Standard English.

Comment: In fact Jack and Jane **have been going out** ever since.